# Is there a way to detect whether an element is obscured by another window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is not to detect whether an element's style is set to visible or physically visible in an active, focused tab. I'd like to know if it's possible to detect whether an element is obscured by another windows using Javascript. If there's no method to call or property to check, would it be possible to use the Javascript repaint event to detect whether the window or a portion of it is obscured?

EDIT: I should say that I'm looking to replace existing functionality where we were able to do this by embedding a flash pixel into the page and calling a function in its paint method. Chrome is preventing this going forward because it apparently causes jank in mobile browsers.

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid. The best you can do is tell that focus is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?